# using variable from array outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, html

Im trying to display variables from an array. I am using a foreach loop, however I need to display  $order['campaign_name'] before the loop so that it only shows up once. How can I do this? If I change it to $orders['campaign_name'] I get an undefined index error.

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="component-table">
              <?php if ($orders) { ?>
              <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=100%><h3><?php echo $order['campaign_name']; ?></h3></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr class="campaign-list" id="campaign-list">
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_owner']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_date']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_code']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: The variable is out of scope, so you can't reference it.

Comment: instead of placing it in the `foreach` you can, above the loop, `echo $orders[0]['campaign_name']`

Comment: Are all the campaign names the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get those value which is not exist before loop. You are directly calling VALUE.
Easily just put index value behind tha array
 echo $orders[0]['campaign_name']
It will print your value.

Answer (score 0):

You would need need to know which index of the array you want to show, but if you want to show the first index of the array you can use `$orders[0]['component_name']`.

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table" id="component-table">
              <?php if ($orders) { ?>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=100%><h3><?php echo $orders[0]['campaign_name']; ?></h3></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>    
                <tr class="campaign-list" id="campaign-list">
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_owner']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['component_date']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $order['campaign_code']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center" colspan="8"><?php echo $text_no_results; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your campaign name continues to echo out because you have it inside of your foreach loop; if you want it to display only once, make sure to place it above your foreach loop.

Here's a less cluttered example to learn from:

```
<table>
...
<?php
if ($orders): 
    echo $order['campaign_name'];
    foreach($orders as $order):
        echo '...'; // other components
    endforeach;
else:
    echo $text_no_results;
endif;
?>
...
</table>
```